# Ajax to PHP form submission. Keep getting "parsererror"

Tags: php, ajax, parse-error

ajaxSubmit.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#submit').click(function() {

    $('#waiting').show(500);
    $('#reg').hide(0);
    $('#message').hide(0);

    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : 'post.php',
        dataType : 'json',
        data: {
            login : $('input#login').val(),
            pass : $('input#pass').val(),
            pass1 : $('input#pass1').val()
        },
        success : function(data){
            $('#waiting').hide(500);
            $('#message').removeClass().addClass((data.error === true) ? 'error' : 'success')
                .text(data.msg).show(500);
            if (data.error === true)
                $('#reg').show(500);
        },
        error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $('#waiting').hide(500);
            $('#message').removeClass().addClass('error')
                .text(textStatus).show(500);
            $('#reg').show(500);
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

});

HTML Form:

```
   <div id="message" style="display: none;">

        </div>
        <div id="waiting" style="display: none;">
            Please wait<br />
            <img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" title="Loader" alt="Loader" />
        <br />
        </div>
  <form id="reg" class="form with-margin" name="reg"  method="post" action="">
            <br />
            <p class="inline-small-label">
                <label for="login"><span class="big">Email</span></label>
                <input type="text"  name="login" id="login" value="">
            </p>
            <p class="inline-small-label">
                <label for="pass"><span class="big">Password</span></label>
                <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass"  value="">
            </p>
            <p class="inline-small-label">
                <label for="pass1"><span class="big">Password Again</span></label>
                <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass1"  value="">
            </p>

            <div align="center"><button type="submit"  name="submit" id="submit" >Register</button></div>

        </form>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ajaxSubmit.js"></script>
```

post.php:

```
    <?php

sleep(3);
$login = $_POST['login'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];
$pass1 = $_POST['pass1'];
$login = mysql_real_escape_string($login);
$pass = mysql_real_escape_string($pass);
$pass1 = mysql_real_escape_string($pass1);



if (empty($login)) {
    $return['error'] = true;
    $return['msg'] = 'You did not enter you email.';
}
else if (empty($pass)) {
    $return['error'] = true;
    $return['msg'] = 'You did not enter you password.';
}
else if ($test == false) {
    $return['error'] = true;
    $return['msg'] = 'Please enter a correct email. This will be verified';
} 
else if (empty($pass)) {
    $return['error'] = true;
    $return['msg'] = 'You did not enter you password twice.';
}
else if ($pass != $pass1) {
    $return['error'] = true;
    $return['msg'] = 'Your passwords dont match.';
}

else {
    $return['error'] = false;
    $return['msg'] = 'Thanks! Please check your email for the verification code!';
}

echo json_encode($return);


?>
```

Any ideas why I keep getting the parsererror?

Comment: *Where* are you getting *what* error exactly?

Comment: from the ajaxsubmit.js the .text(textStatus).show(500); is giving a "parsererror"

Comment: glad to see this got fixed; but please in the future, when quoting errors, always quote the exact message and line. Without that it's often impossible to tell what is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a $test variable `else if ($test == false)` that is undefined.

I'd suggest that if you are having parse errors through ajax, that you just load up the .php file manually and then php will point you to the line that the error is occurring on.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I merely erased some of the code because I though it was unnecessarily but $test is defined.  Its an email validation script I pulled from here. http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/9585?page=0,3 so the parser error can mean a php issue not just a json/ajax issue?

Comment: Update: I am an idiot and thanks sooo much. mysql escape requires access to the sql database so I needed to include the config.php file. THanks again!

Comment: If you load up your php page by itself in the browser do you get any errors on the php page?  Or do the errors only come up when you submit the form?  I'm a bit rusty on my ajax, but if the ajax is returning a result from the PHP page and the PHP page has a parse error in it, then you'll receive that parse error text back from the php page instead of the output you are expecting.